# Connecting Nexus 7 to external hard disk?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-host-mode

How can I connect a Nexus 7 (JB 4.2 rooted) to an external hard disk? I know I have to use a USB OTG cable, but what's the exact procedure to achieve this after connecting via OTG?

Comment: Using it? Where's your problem? Have you tried already and got stuck -- and if so, where did you get stuck? A few more details would be helpful to know what you're pointing at.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

1. Root your Nexus 7
2. Install [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount)
3. Use a file explorer to browse the files on your hard disk

Comment: Note: If the device is an actual spinning-platters hard drive, you may bang your head into the limit of how much current the Nexus 7 will supply.  In that case, you'll need a secondary source of power, like a double-headed USB cable and a charger.

Answer (score 0):

If your Nexus 7 isn't rooted, Install [Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer) app and connect your Hard Disk using USB OTG cable. The app will take care after that.

The question does say that the device is rooted, but this answer can help visitors having unrooted Nexus 7.